# Finding the lowest free position of an array 

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm having a problem with an array, I need to find the lowest free position of an array to insert information into it. How would I go about doing this?

For example I have array `string[] array = String[10]` where by some of the positions of the array are already filled, I need to choose a spot in the array and then search going back to towards position 0 which spots are free and then return that value.

This is probably quite simple but I'm completely stumped, thanks for the help.

Comment: what does it mean that a spot in an array is "free" ? It sounds like you have the wrong data structure for whatever problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Does it have to be efficient? Or will O(N) complexity be sufficient?

Comment: @Tudor: if this code needed to be efficient, OP wouldn't be using an array for this kind of thing (since it will be inefficient in terms of both performance and developer time).

Comment: An array has a fixed size, there are collections that can grow dynamic manner, your question is not clear.  A all elements within a string array which intilized to an empty string

Answer (score 4):

You will need to loop through all indices of the array till you find a `null` entry.

```
for(int i = myArr.Length  - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   if(myArr[i] == null)
   {
       myArr[i] = "no longer free!";
       break;
   }
}
```

If you really need to do something like this, you should probably be using a `List<string>` and not an array.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring why you are doing this - everyone else has told you about `List<string>` - in the below code, `lowest` is equal to 2.

```
var blah = new[] {"one", "two", null, "three"};
var lowest = Array.IndexOf(blah, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a generic list for this:

```
var myList = new List<string>();


//need to add a new item:
myList.Add("New item"); //no searching required
```

You can use a list in most cases just like an array, including access members by subscript.

Comment: Sometimes we lack access to the List. E.g. with NETMF we lack access to generics and might want a typed collection. In that case, using string[] is useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new Instance of `string[]`, its entries are `null`.
Now you just need to iterate through the array until you find the first `null` entry.

```
string[] arrayOfStrings = new string[10];
int index = 0;
while(index < arrayOfStrings.Length && arrayOfStrings[index] != null) index++;
if(index < arrayOfStrings.Length) {
 //arrayOfStrings[index] is lowest free position
} else {
 //every position occupied
}
```

Depending on your problem a `List<string>` instance might be better.
There you can just use its `Add` method to append a string to the last position,
without the need to handle the list length yourself.
And if you need an array as the final result, the `ToArray` method comes in handy.

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
listOfStrings.Add("FirstString");
listOfStrings.Add("SecondString");
string[] arrayOfStrings = listOfStrings.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't ever have to write code like this when working with an array in C#. You're better off storing your strings in a `List<String>` (or a number of other handy collections), which is designed for essentially random access to elements. When you need an actual array of strings, call `.ToArray()` on your `List` collection.

Comment: Sometimes we lack access to the `List`. E.g. with NETMF we lack access to generics and might want a typed collection. In that case, using `string[]` is useful.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: this is true for NETMF, but the question was not tagged with that, so I'm assuming that's not a relevant point. If you do have `List<>`, you should not be rolling your own collection with an array in this manner.

Comment: Let me put it this way. I found your answer unhelpful, because I am using NETMF, and because I want to find the lowest free position of any array. What Oded did is helpful, because he answered the question and then suggested an alternative approach for those who have access to a List.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use a `List<string>` instead, that easily allow you to add elements. Having an array with some null will come back to you later, and you will again check for null... Furtrhermore appending thsat way takes time, is true that the array is small ( yoiu said 10 elements ) but anyway you will spent cpu cycles doing a linear search every time. I think it is possible to try improve the design.

Comment: Sometimes we lack access to the `List`. E.g. with NETMF we lack access to generics and might want a typed collection. In that case, using string[] is useful.

Comment: @ShaunLuttin don't think it deserve a downvote since the OP does not talk abot NETMF, ( probably did not exist at the time of the question )  and more, if you are using a downgraded system there is no reason everybody should downgrade too. If so everybody will program in assembler.

Comment: That's a fair point about NETMF. The OP did not ask about it. The OP did ask about arrays; I came here for an answer to how to find the first null position in an array. Your answer does not answer that. In my opinion, if someone were to have asked about assembler, an answer suggesting to use C# instead would not be appropriate. The sames goes for arrays. And to reverse your argument, if you are using an upgraded system, there is no reason everybody should upgrade too.